# IOS InputStream.read returns -1 but streamError is nil

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to read 4 bytes from a file included as an asset in the Swift project. The stream in the below code is an InputStream, which is created as:

```
let part = fileName.components(separatedBy: ".")
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: part[0], ofType: part[1])
let stream = InputStream.init(fileAtPath: path!)
```

But, for some reason, InputStream.read is returning -1. The documentation states that when -1 is returned more information will be in the streamError field, however the debugger shows this field as nil.

```
var val = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 4)
let bytesRead = stream.read(&val, maxLength: 4)
let err = stream.streamError
let desc = err.debugDescription
```

The file is 100kb long, so it shouldn't be at the end of the stream yet.

Comment: Note that you can just call `let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: nil)` without splitting the file name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must [`open()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/stream/1411963-open)
a stream before you can read or write from it:

```
let stream = InputStream(fileAtPath: path!)
stream.open()
```

Comment: Thanks you save my day.